# if else no detecta variable

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando ver porque no funciona el siguiente if else.
La variable VALUE parece que funciona correctamente, pero al entrar en el if else, no detecta el valor de "true"

```
VALUE=$(curl -s http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/${LIGHT} | jq --compact-output -C '.state.on')
echo $VALUE

if [ "${VALUE}" == "true" ]; then
  echo "${VALUE} | on | Active=1"
else
  echo "${VALUE} | off | Active=0"
fi
```

El resultado es:

```
true
true | off | Active=0
```

porque no entra en la primera condición si el valor de VALUE es "true" ?
Si activo modo debug:

```
+ VALUE='true'
+ echo 'true'
true
+ '[' 'true' == true ']'
+ echo 'true | off | Active=0'
true | off | Active=0
```

Que le pasa al código para que no entre en la primera condición?

Gracias

Comment: Estas seguro que el valor de `VALUE` es `true`? no habrá algún espacio al final?

Comment: cuando ejecuto con el modo debug no aparece espacio. Incluso he puesto "sed 's/ //g' y sigue sin entrar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65384015/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que se me ocurre es ver si la variable `VALUE` tiene algún caracter no imprimible.

Pongo un breve ejemplo:

```
$ VALUE="hola"$'\t\r'  # Tenemos dos caracteres no imprimibles
$ echo $VALUE
hola  # Y no sé ve nada raro. Parece un "hola" común y corriente
[ "${VALUE}" = "hola" ] && echo si || echo no
no  # Pero entró en false
```

Porque si se ve un "true", pero al evaluar la cadena true, te da falso; entonces no es un "true" común y corriente y tiene un caracter no imprimible que el servicio o `jq` le pone, o es un falló de tu shell y sería mejor recompilarla.

Para darle la vuelta, se me ocurre que utilices el doble corchete y rodees la cadena con el carcater `*`:

```
 if [[ "${VALUE}" == *"true"* ]]
 ...
```

**No recomiendo esto**. Considero que es mejor revisar qué tiene la variable `VALUE` con:

```
 $ echo "$VALUE" | cat -A -
 hola^I^M$   #  De mi ejemplo anterior, 
             #+ podemos ver el "tab" (^I) y el retorno de carro (^M).
             #+ Además del final de línea ($) que le agrega echo por defecto.
```

Encerrándola entre comillas dobles, para que no se le escape a `echo` algún caracter.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un signo `=` que sobra, debería ser:

```
if [ "${VALUE}" = "true" ]; then
  echo "${VALUE} | on | Active=1"
else
  echo "${VALUE} | off | Active=0"
fi
```

Comment: mismo resultado: + VALUE='true'
+ echo 'true'
true
+ '[' 'true' = true ']'
+ echo 'true | off | Active=0'
true | off | Active=0

Comment: @Iromeraj, me parece que en Bash, tanto el signo `=` como `==` funcionan para lo mismo. No así en otras shells.

Comment: @Cuauhtli claro, pero para que el operador == funcione debe introducirse entre doble corchete (en este caso). Además el operador == no es estándar.

Comment: @Iromeraj, no necesariamente. De hecho, me parece que `==` entre el keyword `[[` funciona para encontrar un patrón, no para ver igualdad. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

Comment: De todas maneras, me parece que `bash` permite que `==` funcione con el builtin "[",. Claro, ambos sabemos que no es POSIX, pero lo comento porque no veo porque el error tenga que ver con ese signo `=`, a menos que esté usando otra shell como `dash`.